# How to avoid congestion when using Kubernetes pods as Jenkins slaves

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, kubernetes-pod

Our usecase is pretty simple, however, I haven't found a solution for it yet.
In the organization I'm working at, we decided to move to Kubernetes as our container manager in order to spin-up slaves.

Until we moved to this kind of environment, we used to have dedicated slaves per each team. Each got the resources it needs and based on that, it was working.
However, when we moved to use Kubernetes, it started to cause issues as each team shares the same pile of resources, which, can lead to congestion or job failures.

The suggested solution was to create Kubernetes cluster per each team, however, this will lead to burnout of the teams involved with maintanance of multiple clusters.

Searching online, I didn't found any solution avilable, hence, I'm asking here - what is the best way to approach the solution? I understand that we might need to implament a dispacher, but currently it's not possible in the way the Kubernetes plugin is developed.

### Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried dynamic slave pods? each time a build is triggered then the master will create slave pods per team automatically. Are you already following this approach?

Comment: I am Raj, it dosen't limit the issue of resources per team.